# WPF UI thread blocks inside BindingList.OnListChanged

Tags: wpf, bindinglist

I am having a strange problem where occasionally my WPF application deadlocks (blocks forever) inside BindingList<>.OnListChanged() call.

I created my own class, a child of BindingList

```
public class SortableBindingList<tItem> : BindingList<tItem>
{
    //I provide an implementation of ApplySortCore so that the list can be sorted
    protected override void ApplySortCore(PropertyDescriptor aProp,
                                          ListSortDirection aDirection)
    {
        //
        // I perform sorting here by copying items into a different list, sorting
        // and copying back:   this[index] = (tItem)(sortedList[index])
        //

        // Raise the ListChanged event so bound controls refresh their
        // values.
        OnListChanged(new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.Reset, -1)); 
     }
 }
```

The problem occurs deep inside OnListChanged().  The UI thread blocks forever waiting on something.

```
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherSynchronizationContext.Wait(System.IntPtr[] waitHandles, bool waitAll, int millisecondsTimeout)  Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.InvokeWaitMethodHelper(System.Threading.SynchronizationContext syncContext, System.IntPtr[] waitHandles, bool waitAll, int millisecondsTimeout)    Unknown
[Native to Managed Transition]  
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.SystemResources.FindResourceInternal(object key, bool allowDeferredResourceReference, bool mustReturnDeferredResourceReference)    Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.FindResourceInternal(System.Windows.FrameworkElement fe, System.Windows.FrameworkContentElement fce, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, object resourceKey, object unlinkedParent, bool allowDeferredResourceReference, bool mustReturnDeferredResourceReference, System.Windows.DependencyObject boundaryElement, bool isImplicitStyleLookup, out object source)  Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.StyleHelper.GetChildValueHelper(System.Windows.UncommonField<System.Collections.Specialized.HybridDictionary[]> dataField, ref MS.Utility.ItemStructList<System.Windows.ChildValueLookup> valueLookupList, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, System.Windows.DependencyObject container, MS.Internal.FrameworkObject child, int childIndex, bool styleLookup, ref System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry entry, out System.Windows.ValueLookupType sourceType, System.Windows.FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot) Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.StyleHelper.GetChildValue(System.Windows.UncommonField<System.Collections.Specialized.HybridDictionary[]> dataField, System.Windows.DependencyObject container, int childIndex, MS.Internal.FrameworkObject child, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, ref MS.Utility.FrugalStructList<System.Windows.ChildRecord> childRecordFromChildIndex, ref System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry entry, out System.Windows.ValueLookupType sourceType, System.Windows.FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot)  Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.StyleHelper.GetValueFromStyleOrTemplate(MS.Internal.FrameworkObject fo, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, ref System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry entry)    Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.GetRawValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata metadata, ref System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry entry) Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.EvaluateBaseValueCore(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata metadata, ref System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry newEntry)    Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.EvaluateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.EntryIndex entryIndex, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata metadata, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry newEntry, System.Windows.OperationType operationType)  Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.EntryIndex entryIndex, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata metadata, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, ref System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry newEntry, bool coerceWithDeferredReference, bool coerceWithCurrentValue, System.Windows.OperationType operationType) Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.InvalidateProperty(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, bool preserveCurrentValue) Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.StyleHelper.InvalidateResourceDependents(System.Windows.DependencyObject container, System.Windows.ResourcesChangeInfo info, ref MS.Utility.FrugalStructList<System.Windows.ChildPropertyDependent> resourceDependents, bool invalidateVisualTreeToo)  Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.TreeWalkHelper.InvalidateStyleAndReferences(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, System.Windows.ResourcesChangeInfo info, bool containsTypeOfKey)    Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.TreeWalkHelper.OnResourcesChanged(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, System.Windows.ResourcesChangeInfo info, bool raiseResourceChangedEvent)  Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnAncestorChangedInternal(System.Windows.TreeChangeInfo parentTreeState)  Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.TreeWalkHelper.OnAncestorChanged(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, System.Windows.TreeChangeInfo info, bool visitedViaVisualTree) Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.DescendentsWalker<System.Windows.TreeChangeInfo>.StartWalk(System.Windows.DependencyObject startNode, bool skipStartNode)  Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.PrePostDescendentsWalker<System.Windows.TreeChangeInfo>.StartWalk(System.Windows.DependencyObject startNode, bool skipStartNode)  Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.TreeWalkHelper.InvalidateOnTreeChange(System.Windows.FrameworkElement fe, System.Windows.FrameworkContentElement fce, System.Windows.DependencyObject parent, bool isAddOperation) Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnVisualParentChanged(System.Windows.DependencyObject oldParent)  Unknown
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.Visual.FireOnVisualParentChanged(System.Windows.DependencyObject oldParent)   Unknown
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.Visual.RemoveVisualChild(System.Windows.Media.Visual child)   Unknown
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.VisualCollection.DisconnectChild(int index)   Unknown
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.VisualCollection.Clear()  Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection.ClearInternal()   Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Panel.ClearChildren() Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Panel.EnsureEmptyChildren(System.Windows.FrameworkElement logicalParent)  Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Panel.OnItemsChangedInternal(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ItemsChangedEventArgs args)    Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingPanel.OnItemsChangedInternal(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ItemsChangedEventArgs args)    Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Panel.OnItemsChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ItemsChangedEventArgs args)    Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.OnRefresh()    Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.OnCollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)   Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.WeakEventManager.ListenerList<System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>.DeliverEvent(object sender, System.EventArgs e, System.Type managerType)  Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.WeakEventManager.DeliverEvent(object sender, System.EventArgs args)  Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Collections.Specialized.CollectionChangedEventManager.OnCollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)   Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.OnCollectionChanged(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)  Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.OnViewCollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)  Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.WeakEventManager.ListenerList<System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>.DeliverEvent(object sender, System.EventArgs e, System.Type managerType)  Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.WeakEventManager.DeliverEvent(object sender, System.EventArgs args)  Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Collections.Specialized.CollectionChangedEventManager.OnCollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)   Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.OnCollectionChanged(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)  Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingListCollectionView.RefreshOverride()   Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.RefreshInternal()  Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.RefreshOrDefer()   Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingListCollectionView.OnListChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs args)   Unknown
System.dll!System.ComponentModel.BindingList<System.__Canon>.OnListChanged(System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs e)    Unknown
```

I cannot figure out why it would block.  I only access this list on the UI thread, not any other thread.

Thank you very much for any info.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to do this

```
// Raise the ListChanged event so bound controls refresh their
// values.
OnListChanged(new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.Reset, -1));
```

Remove that one, `BindingList`. The UI should listen to updates like **Sorting, Searching, Add, etc.**

Comment: Thanks! This change seems to avoid the deadlock(?) but controls bound to this list no longer update.  I have a DataGrid bound to SortableBindingList.

Comment: You'll have to raise `PropertyChanged` on the `Collection` that the `ViewModel` is bound to. So that it'll update